# How to replace grouped dataframe with dict pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
date | brand | red | blue | green
---------------------------------
2017 | BMW   |  2  |  1   |   0
     |  GM   |  0  |  1   |   0
2018 | BMW   |  0  |  0   |   1
     |  GM   |  1  |  2   |   0
```

Which is result of following line:

```
pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),index=['date','brand'],columns='color',values='index',aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

Applied to this initial DataFrame:

```
date | brand | color
--------------------
2017 | BMW   | red
2017 | GM    | blue
2017 | BMW   | blue
2017 | BMW   | red
2018 | BMW   | green
2018 | GM    | blue
2018 | GM    | blue
2018 | GM    | red
```

Is it possible to somehow replace entries BMW, GM in grouped dataframe with dictionary, let's say

```
di = {'BMW': 1, 'GM': 2}
```

I tried simple `df.replace({'brand': di})`, but it appears that brand column is not in dataframe, despite I can see it.

Comment: Do you want `df = df.replace(di)` ?

Comment: Initial is very big, so it takes a lot of time. Grouped otherwise has just few entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) for replace values of `MultiIndex` by `di`:

```
df = df.rename(di)
#same as
#df = df.rename(index=di)
print (df)
color       blue  green  red
date brand                  
2017 1       1.0    0.0  2.0
     2       1.0    0.0  0.0
2018 1       0.0    1.0  0.0
     2       2.0    0.0  1.0
```

When you pass a dict to `rename` when ever the function comes across the `key` it will be replaced by `value`.

Comment: It works, I just don't understand how it knows what to rename?

Comment: I think it is shorcuts of `df = df.rename(index=di)`

Comment: and `index` is default value, so it working. For replace columns is used `df = df.rename(columns=di)`

Comment: So if I have 'BMW' in date column it still will be renamed?

Comment: No, because no columns keyword.